# linux|awk|shell script block deletion

Tags: linux, shell, awk, gawk

My input file has blocks like below. Please help me deleting the block and its contents using awk or sed

```
[abc]  
para1=123  
para2=456  
para3=111  

[pqr]  
para1=333    
para2=765    
para3=1345    

[xyz]    
para1=888    
para2=236    
para3=964
```

now how do i delete a block and its parameters completely .Please help me achieve this with awk command.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl solution to remove block `[abc]`

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN{$/=""} print "$_\n" unless /^\[abc\]/' file
```

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file, put the line in the $_ variable, do not automatically print the line
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-e` execute the perl code

`$/` is the input record separator.  Setting it to `""` in a `BEGIN{}` block puts Perl into paragraph mode.
`$_` is the current line.
`/^/` is a regular expression which begins with the search term

output:

```
[pqr]  
para1=333    
para2=765    
para3=1345    

[xyz]    
para1=888    
para2=236    
para3=964
```

This variation enables argument parsing with `-s` and passes [abc] to variable `$b`

```
perl -slne 'BEGIN{$/=""} print "$_\n" unless /^$b/' -- -b='\[abc\]'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RS` for split blocks, (NOTE: `NR>1` because awk generate a empty block in beginning)

```
awk -vRS='[' -v remove="pqr" '
   NR>1 && $0 !~ "^"remove"]" {printf "%s", "["$0; }
' file
```

you get,

```
[abc]
para1=123
para2=456
para3=111

[xyz]
para1=888
para2=236
para3=964
```

Comment: Nice idea. You can simplify: `awk -F ']' -v RS='[' -v ORS='[' -v remove="pqr" '$1 != remove'`, plus a step to tidy the stray ORS at the end of the output

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the idea, but however this doesn't work good when i have the input in the blocks like 
[abc]
1=[run]
2=[stop]


please help me with the command for the same

Comment: @VigneshJei Pursell's solution is better, it's working fine with this input

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you want to filter.  If you want to delete the block with the header '[pqr]'

```
awk '!/^\[pqr\]/' RS= ORS='\n\n' input
```

or

```
awk '$1 !~ "[pqr]"' RS= ORS='\n\n' input
```

If you want to omit the 2nd record (the same as above)

```
awk 'NR!=2' RS= ORS='\n\n' input
```

If you want to omit the record in which para2=765,

```
awk '$3 !~ "765"' RS= ORS='\n\n' input
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a slightly different solution using only shell.

```
#!/bin/sh 

# specify the block to withhold
WITHHOLD=2

COUNT=1
INAWHITESP=0

while read i
do if [ -z "$i" -a "$INAWHITESP" -eq 0 ]
   then COUNT=$(( COUNT + 1 ))
        INAWHITESP=1
   fi
   if [ -n "$i" -a "$INAWHITESP" -eq 1 ]
   then INAWHITESP=0
   fi
   if [ "$COUNT" -ne "$WITHHOLD" ]
   then printf "%s\n" "$i"
   fi

done < inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove block `abc`

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""} !/\[abc\]/'
```